# Create an entity within an entity

Tags: 7, entities

Hopefully there is something out there to do what I want. I imagine my terminology is off hence why my googling is failing.

I have two content types.

Album & Track.

I want to create a new Album. When creating an Album I want to be able to reference tracks to it. I know I could create the tracks first then use the entityreference module to add those tracks to the album.

What I want to do is to create the Tracks on the fly. So have an Add track button, fill in the fields for track and then for it to be associated with the album.

For my purpose Track does not need to be it's own content type but I need to able to capture more than one field when pressing the add button.

Any ideas if there is anything out there for this?

If not I can try hacking together something in code.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use references and something like the [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) module.

> Provides a widget for inline management (creation, modification,
>   removal) of referenced entities. The primary use case is the parent ->
>   children one (product display -> products, order -> line items, etc.),
>   where the child entities are never managed outside the parent form.
>   Existing entities can also be referenced.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_autocreate could be an option. Never had to use it but have it bookmarked for when I eventually will. Can't help with instructions.